# Does not start .jar file after double click

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, jar

I have a problem with `.jar` files created by Eclipse.

My problem is that the `.jar` files created by Eclipse of JavaFX-Applications won't start as `.jar` files.
If you try to start them with a double-click only the little blue "loading" circle appears for a second.

If I start the `.jar` file with cmd or PowerShell with the "java -jar xxx.jar" command it starts without any problems.

When exporting an `.jar` file (Runnable JAR File) in Eclipse I select the main class of the project as launch configuration and "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" as library handling.

I have JDK 11 and 8 as well as JRE 8 installed.

I looked up the default app for `.jar` file type in the settings.
For `.jar` files "Java(TM) Platform SE binary" was shown as default app for `.jar` files.
I don't know which version of Java this stands for but I think it's the JRE.

Then I also tried to start the `.jar` file with the other Java installations using "right-click -> open with -> choose another app" and then I selected the javaw.exe of the JDK 11 and 8 but both times again only the blue "loading" circle appeared.

I did some research on the internet and on stackoverflow but I didn't find any answers that solved my problem.

I am using Windows 10 and Eclipse 2019-06.
The JavaFX-Applications are using JDK 8.

```
MANIFEST.MF:

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Main-Class: application.Main

Class-Path: .


Name: about.html

SHA-256-Digest: 1fuYr0bu6NsJZCAmSom5QtnvnV0Cg8DwLn77Dd1Ql24=


Name: jfx8.cssext

SHA-256-Digest: b2p9PXeoxqnTdYgBFeKp3s7J9PajukOS3sGqyM4s36I=
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with File Type association or Open With functionality, as well as with double-click is that the application (in your case javaw.exe or java.exe) is executed without parameters or more precisely with one parameter - the name of your jar file.
It is a known problem since Windows XP. Previously you could use ftype as assoc commands:

```
ftype MyJAR=C:\your java path\java.exe -jar "%1"
assoc .jar=MyJAR
```

But it will update registry keys for HKLM\Software\Classes and not for HKCU (which takes precedence) in newer Windows versions.
I would recommend to use nice free utility written by Nir Sofer http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html
It supports Windows 10 and you will be able to define -jar parameter properly